# ssh or openssh not listed in the Ubuntu Software program

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to install ssh on a fresh install of 16.04 LTS but it is not listed in Ubuntu Software program

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the client or the server?

If the box you want to install this on is the one you want to control then you want server run this command:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

If you just want a client, although I have never installed this myself ssh from the terminal has always worked, but here is the command to install:

```
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

If you want more info, please go to this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

I hope this helps, Chris